# Suggested edits view only partially visible when using "Full site" in mobile

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, responsive-design

Although the review queue works fine, if I try to review a pending suggested edit by visiting the post and then clicking on edit(1), the view for the review is only partially visible. I cannot horizontally scroll, neither can I zoom out.

Here's how it looks in Chrome v71.x (latest as of now in Play Store). I can do a vertical scroll only.

[image]

This is worse when opened in portrait mode. In Firefox for Android:

[image: IMG:]

In both the browsers I was using the Full site option available at the bottom of a StackExchange site. The edits are loaded fine when Desktop site option, as available in both the browsers, is used.