# Responses layout distorted when using "Full site" in mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, activity

Under Activity section of user profile, when I load the comments under responses, the layout seems out of place.

This happens both in Chrome and Firefox for Android. I am using the latest version available for them in Play Store. This happens both when Full site option (available at the bottom of an Stack Exchange site) or Request Desktop site feature of browser is used. Furthermore, this happens only in Portrait mode.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Many of the pages on the site, and the profile pages in particular are not yet responsive - meaning they don't scale to fit the screen size they're on. This is in progress but not yet complete. This is not specific to the mobile web.

Comment: @Catija Okay. Is [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323549/286110) also about responsive design?

Comment: Possibly. I can check. We're slowly transitioning all of those elements over to Stacks (there's a lot of them!), which is likely the bigger problem, as that one hasn't been redone yet. To see the difference between the old and new overlays, look at the post flag dialogue (click "flag" on any question/answer) vs the comment flag (click the flag icon on a comment) dialogue. I'm guessing the former will fail in a similar way while the latter works just fine in your mobile browser.

Comment: @Catija thanks for all of this info. The flag dialogue doesn't fail in both portrait and landscape modes, but the differences in the design are visible.